# Git - Applying the same changes more than once

Tags: git

Our team is developing an application and using git for version control. We use master branch for release versions and creating new branches for bug-fixes and development.

The problem is: the development environment has some differences with release environment, we need to change port values and database connections for some files in order to work correctly on development. So everytime I create a branch I use a patch command from a diff I previously created and and a patch again after I finish my work to merge with master again.

So when I create a new branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch
patch < changes.diff
```

And when I finish:

```
patch -R < changes.diff
git add *
git commit -m "new things"
```

I think there should be a git command for me to do these patches on git, since these seem so similar to what git should be doing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason why there (probably) isn't a good git command for this is because there are other, better, ways of handling your situation. The typical way to handle this is to have a configuration file *template* committed to your repository, containing the default values, or placeholders. Every developer would then make a copy of this *template* into the *actual configuration file*, and this *actual configuration file* would be ignored by the git repository, but be the one that is loaded by your application. You then make local changes to this file, and these are never committed.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yeah I thought about adding them to gitignore. But the problem is we are also frequently making changes on these files, the top patched part stays the same but we add new things to bottom, so we want git to also follow them.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but git doesn't have a good way of dealing with this because there are alternatives that are sort of the accepted standard. Many applications support multiple configuration files, or they have build steps that combine configuration files into one, this would also allow you to have one configuration file committed to the repository and one that the developer would need to create him/her-self with local environment configurations.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen thanks for helping with development patterns, we may reconfigure the repository in future but currently git stash apply and reverse apply solves our needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at git [`stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) command. Basically you need yo stash your changes and aplly/pop to new branch. Than you can select what you want to commit and leave changes from stash or unapply from its head using `git stash show` command for example. That apply stashed changes to a new branch, for example

Comment: This is a good advice to apply the patch, but when I finish my work is there a way to unapply the stash or do I need to manually choose which parts to add to the commit.

Comment: @BrokenFrog you can select what you want to commit and and leave changes from stash. That apply it to a new branch, for example

Comment: I found a way to unapply stash after my work is finished. It's like `$ git stash show -p stash@{0} | git apply -R` to unapply changes to the git. Thanks for the stash suggestion.

Can you add the unapplying to your answer for me to accept as solved.